# how to call a formula field in visual force pages

Tags: visualforce, opportunity, formula-field

Can any one help me out.I have a custom visual force page created.I would like to call a formula field in VF page.Any suggestion plz

I have a visual force page created in PDF format. I have few of the products with different names in different product family. If the product line for the product selected in opportunity items is ‘DIE’ make following changes .

1) unit price should change to $.01.

Unit price just change on the PDF display only and with extended amount which will be quantity times .01.

2)Extension is a custom formula field on opportunity products with (Quantity*1).Subtotal & total amount due  as custom Roll up  Summary field on Opportunity object which is equal to Extension.

The First Step is got resolved.In second step the value of subtotal reflects as per the formula of extension ,but the value should get refleced as per the extension value on PDF. **For both of them the sub totals and total amount due are not aligned with what is out in lines as line total.**

**PFA SCREEN SHOT**[image]

**Visual Force Code :**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" renderAs="pdf" applyhtmltag="false" showHeader="false" applyBodyTag="false" extensions="InvoiceController">


    <table >
        <tr>
            <td class="header-table-heading">LN</td>
           <!-- <td class="header-table-heading">Name</td>-->
            <td class="header-table-heading">BinItemCode</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Customer Item #<b/></td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">COO</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">ECCN #</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">UOM</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Unit Price</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Quantity</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Extension</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="header-table-heading"></td>
            <td colspan="9" style="text-align:left"  class="header-table-heading">Description</td>
        </tr>
        <apex:repeat value="{!appointmentList}" var="line">
        <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!if(line.pick==true, true, false)}">

        <tr>         
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!line.LineNumber}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <!--<td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!line.productname}"></apex:outputText></td>-->
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!line.BinItemCode}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"></td>
            <td class="header-table-data">8541.40.2000</td>
            <td class="header-table-data">EA</td>
           <!-- <td class="header-table-data">$1</td>-->
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputtext value="{!line.unitprice}"></apex:outputtext></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputtext value="{!line.quantity}"></apex:outputtext></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!line.extension}"></apex:outputText></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="header-table-data"></td>

            <td colspan="8" style="text-align:left" class="header-table-data"><b>Scheduled Ship Date:</b>
                        <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
                                <apex:param value="{!line.Scheduledshipdate}"/>
                        </apex:outputText> </td>
        </tr>
        </apex:outputPanel>    
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Gross Weight</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Net Weight</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Shipped Via</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Tracking #</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Payment Terms</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Incoterms </td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Currency </td>
            <td rowspan="0" class="header-table-heading">Sub Total <br/>Shipping Charges</td>
            <td rowspan="0" class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.Pick_Total__c}"></apex:outputText>
                 <br/><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Shipping_Charges__c}"></apex:outputText><br/></td>

        </tr>
        <apex:repeat value="{!appointmentList1}" var="line1">
        </apex:repeat>
        <tr>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Gross_Weight__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Net_weight__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Shipped_Via__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Bill_of_Lading__c}"> </apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data">Net 30</td>
            <td class="header-table-data">EXW</td>
            <td class="header-table-data">USD</td>
            <td rowspan="0" class="header-table-heading"> Total Amount Due</td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.Pick_Total__c + opportunity.Shipping_Charges__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class :**

```
for(integer i=0; i < OPplineitem.size(); i++)
                   {
                     tempObj = new wrapperClass();
                     tempObj.productname= OPplineitem[i].PricebookEntry.Product2.Name;
                     tempObj.BinItemCode=OPplineitem[i].Bin_Item_Code__c;
                     tempObj.quantity=OPplineitem[i].Quantity;
                     tempObj.totalamount=OPplineitem[i].Sys_total_Amount__c;
                    // tempObj.productline=OPplineitem[i].PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Line__c;
                     //Add a conditional statement here


                 if(OPplineitem[i].PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Line__c=='DIE') 
                     {
                      tempObj.unitprice=0.01;
                      tempobj.extension=OPplineitem[i].Quantity * tempObj.unitprice;
                     }
                 else
                     {
                     tempObj.unitprice=OPplineitem[i].ListPrice;
                     tempobj.extension=OPplineitem[i].Extension__c;
                     }
                     tempobj.LineNumber=OPplineitem[i].LN__c;
                     tempobj.Pick= OPplineitem[i].Pick__c;
                     tempobj.ScheduledShipDate = Opplineitem[i].schedule_ship_date__c;

                     if(tempobj!=null){
                        aReList.add(tempObj);
                     }
                    }
           return aReList;
   }
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to display a formula field and, when the inputs to that formula change, reflect those changes in that formula field?

Comment: @BarCotter:I have update with the code.

Comment: @Koen Wesselman,@John Westenhaver:i have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Displaying formula fields works the same way as displaying any other type of field. Please have a look at the following link for more information on displaying fields:

https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_display_field_values.htm

If this doesn't help, please add your Visualforce and Apex code to your question.